# what is the difference between git pull , git fetch and git rebase?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

What are the differences between `git pull` ,  `git fetch` and `git rebase`? I feel pull and fetch are same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch

Comment: I suggest you read [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). The first three chapters cover 95% of what you need on a daily basis, including the answer to your question.

Comment: `git pull --rebase` is equivalent to the latter two

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fetch:** update **local** with **remote changes** but **not merge** with any **local branch**.

**Pull:** update **local** and **merge** the changes with **current-branch**.

- `git fetch`: Get the latest changes from origin (no merge)
- `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`
- If you rebase `feature` branch onto `master` branch. `git rebase master`, it would keep the `feature` branch `commits/changes` top.

  Say you have two commits in `master` branch (`A` -> `C`) and two commits in `feature` branch (`B` -> `D`).

  Assume you are in `feature` branch (`git checkout feature`). Now if you `merge master` then commit history:

  ```
  (previous commit) - A -- C       <- master
                    \        \
                      B -- D -- M   <- feature
  ```

  Here, `M` for `new-merge-commit-sha`.

  For `rebase master`, commit history: (`A` -> `C` -> `B'` -> `D'`).

Comment: Usually you would rebase `feature` onto `master`, not the other way around.

Comment: And `git merge master` will result in a much more complicated commit history than what you have shone.

Comment: Agree @Code-Apprentice, here I tried to show the `simple/generic` difference.

Comment: Keeping it simple is fine as long as it is correct. As you have it here, the commit history is incorrect in your paragraph about `git merge`.

Comment: Also, the wording describing rebase is incorrect. `git rebase master` will rebase the current branch onto `master`.

Comment: Yes, here I assume current branch is `feature`. `git checkout feature`, `git rebase master`. So, it will rebase the `feature` onto `master`.

Comment: Please edit your answer to say so.

Comment: I metioned it in answer already. `"Assume you are in feature branch. Now if you merge master then..."`

Comment: What does that quote have to do with rebase? I'm talking about "If you rebase master branch into feature branch. git rebase master..." which is incorrect. You do not rebase master branch into feature branch, rather you rebase feature branch *onto* master branch.

Comment: I see (it was mistake), Thanks.

Comment: You should also fix your commit history illustrations to show a correct merge history.

Comment: Fixed commit history!

Comment: The commit history for `git merge` still is not correct. The history will not be linear.

Comment: Edited. Seems ok now?